# Swiss keyboard - clamps

Tags: 12.04, keyboard

For my IT-project I need to use bracket characters. But with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> it doesn't work. What are the combinations and where I can edit these? It's very heavy to work with other keyboard combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd>.
With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> it doesn't work for me neither.
I don't think this can be edited.

Btw.: Which swiss keyboard shows Strg instead of Ctrl?

Comment: Hi the_Seppi

Thank you very much for you answer - it works.